# Closing with buttons won't end task C#

Tags: c#

So for some reason when I code `this.Close();` into my program it won't actually close it. 
I have the program open a different .exe file then close, but I open my task manager and it actually is still running in the background. I have this issue with the "Close" option on my context menu also. 
Any ideas why?

EDIT: Even when I exit with the button, it's still in the background.

EDIT:

```
private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void launch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%\\program.exe"));
    this.Close();
}
```

Only actual two codes that are closing the program. But it's still running in the background.
Even when I exit through the actual x button, it still runs in the background.

Comment: can you please show us your code?

Comment: Do you mean you have an application that runs another executable?

Comment: try `Application.Exit();`

Comment: @sickUnit I tried that, it worked. Except when using the exit button built in already....hm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must close the process that you've created. Create a variable to save the process that has been created and when you close the form or press another button close process. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Process _process;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this._process = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this._process != null) {
                this._process.CloseMainWindow();
                this._process.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OHHHHH, so I was simply closing the form. I need to close the whole process? Okay, now it makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: Yes! you were closing the form and not closing the process:)

Comment: Still having trouble though. It's putting the red line under Process. Can you explain more of how this code is working so I can properly put it into my program?

Comment: @Matthew add `using System.Diagnostics;` to your "using"-block or use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe");`

Comment: Indeed, a reference to  System.Diagnostics is required. I shall include it in the code sample

Answer (score 0):

As menstion in above comment add using System.Diagnostics; to your code and try this code

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);
}

void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
}
```

Comment: Still having the issue with the exit button not completely closing it. Could it be at the fact that I have a splash screen? The splash screen is running in the background because of `this.Hide();` but if I put anything else, the whole program will close. And ideas?

Comment: for this you have two use thread means Starting two forms on separate threads also Invoking an EventHandler to shutdown a form on a separate thread and Creating a threaded timer
for more information check this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446493.aspx